# Using TransactionScope to cleanup after specflow UI tests

Tags: entity-framework, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, transactionscope, specflow

I have a legacy ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms application for which I want to build some end-to-end tests. I use Specflow to create the tests and Selenium WebDriver to script Firefox.

The application is using simple ADO.NET to access the DB (MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1).

I want to achieve test isolation so everything one test writes in the DB I want it deleted at the end of the test so I use the following approach:

```
        [BeforeScenario]
        public void ScenarioSetup()
        {

            Scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                                         new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel =    IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted});
            Browser.CreateNew();
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void ScenarioCleanup()
        {
            if (Scope != null)
            {
                Scope.Dispose();
            }
            Browser.Close();
        }
```

So opening a transaction scope and disposing it at the end.

In the **Given** block I open up an EF5 DbContext and write some setup data:

```
  public void GivenIHaveAccountsWithDifferentStatusesInTheSystem()
    {
        using (var ctx = new WorkflowImprovementsContext())
        {
            try
            {
                _contact = new Contact()
                {
                    created = new DateTime(2010, 1, 18),
                    countryId = 1,
                    stateId = 1,
                    contactName = "Account Contact Name One",
                    companyName = "Company Company Account One",
                    address1 = "Address 1 One",
                    address2 = "Address 2 One",
                    city = "City Account One",
                    email = "Email Account One",
                    zipCode = "A123",
                    phone = "0735352244",
                    mobile = "0735352244",
                    pager = "0735352244",
                    fax = "0735352244",
                    webSite = "www.test.com"
                };
                ctx.Contacts.Add(_contact);

                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }

        }
```

Notice the context gets disposed after usage.

I run my specflow tests from withing ReSharper test runner. The test at some point in the **When** step of the test starts-up Firefox(separate process) and scripts the browser to go to a page where via an AJAX call the data that was just put in the DB is getting read.

This is where I'm stuck, the AJAX call won't return (the code in the web service behind it waits for DB access) until I dispose of the TransactionScope.

Why does the app in the Firefox process can't read the data written from within the test runner process? (the TS is ReadUncommitted, and I tried all others but still no luck)

I can't dispose of the scope earlier because that would defeat the purpose, I need to make an assert later on after reading the data and then dispose the TS and with it the data in DB would be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are trying to create data in your database within an open transaction and read those same data from a different transaction in a different process while the transaction is still open and uncommitted.  that is not going to work with the default isolation level for a transaction scope.  unless you are using ReadUncommitted in your application or using a nolock hint on the query in the application, you are not going to be able to read that information until the transaction commits.

you probably don't want to allow your application to read uncommitted data - this is why relational databases adhere to the ACID properties and use transactions.  if you can read uncommitted information, you can have bad things happen in your application.  that could be ok for your application - but if it's not something you are doing because your application should be doing it, i wouldn't advise doing it just for tests.

i've never liked the idea of using transactions to remove data in tests anyway - seems like using transactions in a way they were not really intended and messy.  it's better in a single process where you're doing everything all your test setup and teardown and execution of application code in a single transaction, but i'm not crazy about it even there.

really, you might be overthinking and making this too difficult.  if what you want is to create data before you execute the action under test and delete them after, maybe you should just do the simplest thing possible and just add before and delete after.  i dislike it more in what you are doing where you are actually hitting the application accross a process boundary.